# how to link a product tables of a distributor and many retail outlets relations? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

how to link a product tables of a distributor and retail outlets relations?

There are two products table.

One is all product table with some information and another is some products with additional information.

```
       distributor                     retailer 1
------------------------      --------------------
id  |  name  | expiredate       id  |  price | info
1                               1
2                               3
3
```

There are a lot of retailer more than 100 tables.

What I want to do is retailer 1 open the product page. all product will be displayed with checkbox and available product will be checked.

can I extract with one query?

Any better approach, to handle many retailers, are welcome.

Comment: If the retailer tables all have the same structure, then I'd recommend only having a single table for them all; just adding a retailer ID to distinguish

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank for your reply. Some retailer are the same but some are different. If I put in same table record will be thousands. I'm afraid of performance. Bcoz most of retailer r using 128kbps. :(

Comment: when you say "more than 100 tables". did you mean to say rows?

Comment: Do you have more fields?  I read your comment in Logan's answer, and I'm confused on the question even more...

Comment: No. Logan. 
I'm developing for distributor that has many outlets and retailers. They sell many types of casual wear clothes. So many outlets with many products. each outlets has many products. So many outlet means many many products. Some outlet are small town. Their connections is so slow. That's why I decided to break table for each retailer.

Comment: @user2710326 i think a database with over 100 tables is bad...you have a table for each distributor, outlet, and retailer? I cannot even imagine what a query would look like...so many joins

Comment: The server processing won't really hurt the end users...  You should always use proper database architecture.

Comment: Thanks @dougjore. Then I'll try to marges same retailers in one table. 
Hi Logan. I'm junior programmer, Just graduated. Thank for your suggestion. I thought each retailer will use only their related tables. I have never imagine to query with so many join. maximum join is 3, I thought.

Comment: Yes, retailer table may have some more additional information. such as prices. Distributor sell different price with different retailer.

Comment: Database tables can easily handle thousands of millions of rows when properly indexed, so it shouldn't cause performance overheads having a single retailer table, and having over 100 individual retailers tables will cause you a lot of problems if you need to look across different retailers - this sounds like a case of bad design based on unjustified fears of performance

Comment: Prices shouldn't be in a retailer table, they should be in a retailer_products or a retailer_product_prices table or some form of cross-reference table

Comment: Thanks All. I got a lot of helpful suggestion. I don't breakdown retailer_product table. But as Logan said, I'll use a bridge table for retailer and product tables. Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 0):

if each retailer can have many distributors and each distributor can have many retailers then you are looking for a `many-to-many` relationship which would require a new table

```
distributor_retailer
--------------------
distributor_retailer_id | retailer_id | distributer_id 
1                         1             1
2                         1             2
3                         2             1
```

where `retailer_id` and `distributor_id` are `foreign keys` to the respective tables.

with this data retailer 1 deals with distributors 1 and 2. Also retailer 2 deals is distributor 1.

You can also look at it the other way around. Distributor 1 deals with retailer 1 and 2. Also distributor 2 deals with retailer 1.

Comment: HI logan, 
I think your answer is a bit out of my questions. retailer will open distributor web app to offer some products (either available product or new product.). I want to display all product with checkbox and available are checked. It can be done with two query. I'm looking for one query. 

Anyway thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I used only product table and product_retailer_bridge table

```
SELECT product.*,  product_retailer_bridge.*  
(CASE WHEN product_retailer_bridge.`retailer_id`=1 THEN
product_retailer_bridge.`retailer_id` ELSE NULL END ) AS test 
FROM product LEFT JOIN product_retailer_bridge ON 
(product.`product_id` = product_retailer_bridge.`product_id`)
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.*, product_retailer_bridge.* FROM product LEFT JOIN
product_retailer_bridge ON product.`product_id`= product_retailer_bridge.`product_id`
AND product_retailer_bridge.`retailer_id`=1 GROUP BY product.`product_id`
```

Thank you all. Code is credited to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003490/many-to-many-relationship-select-checkboxes-in-form-php) link. 
Thank @logan, @Mark, @dianuj and @klkvsk.